# Is there a place on this site to put our articles?

Tags: support

Is there a place on this site to put our articles?

Another question: does this site have a resources page? Like [AoPS resources page](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/resources.php), I mean.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Amir just asked a question about the site, isn't that what the meta is all about?

Comment: Dear Amir and @Lovre, Downvotes on meta question often indicate disagreement with the (implicit, in this case) proposal in the question.  So I would guess that in this case the downvote indicates (a) there is no place on the site to put articles; and (b) the downvoter doesn't want there to be such a place.  Up/downvotes on meta don't affect rep., precisely (as far as I understand) so that this sort of downvoting to indicate agreement/disagreement can take place.  Regards,

Answer (score 17):

No, and no. This site is only for asking and answering specific mathematical questions.

Comment: I heard some talks about an accompanying blog though...

Comment: @Aryabhata, @Qiaochu btw, yes, [BlogOverflow](http://blogoverflow.com/)